# Issue with loading csv with ejml

Tags: java, file, csv, ejml

I'm encountering some problems by using the `MatrixIO.loadcsv()` function in ejml. In fact, I need to load a file into a matrix; i'm following this [official example](https://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Input_and_Output#CSV_Input.2FOutut):

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
DMatrixRMaj A = new DMatrixRMaj(2,3,true,new double[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});

try {
    MatrixIO.saveCSV(A, "matrix_file.csv");
    DMatrixRMaj B = MatrixIO.loadCSV("matrix_file.csv");
    B.print();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

But when I try my code

```
DMatrixRMaj B = MatrixIO.loadCSV("sets.csv");
B.print();
```

I always obtain a FileNotFoundException... but the name of the file is correct and in the same folder of the source code. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me (I'm using Windows 10) is to use absolute path, because it seems not to recognize relative ones on my system, despite of the official examples.